# Javascript won't load with .js.erb extension

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a javascript file in my rails site which loads fine with the extension .js.

I need to use an image helper tag in it, so according to the documentation I need to add an erb extension to - making it .js.erb.

As soon as I change the extension to .js.erb (leaving the javascript file as is, IE no ruby) it breaks and the javascript no longer works.

When I check it with chrome inspector the javascript contents are as follows:

```
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

However it is fine when the extension is just .js.

What am I doing wrong?

edit:: without the .erb extension the relevent javascript line is returning this in chrome inspector:

```
function fancyViewReport() {
    return '<div class="demo-report-title"><a class="fancyReport" href="<%= asset_path 'demoreport.png' %>">Click <u>here</u> to view a demo report!</a></div>';
}
```

this javascript file is being called through application.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `js.erb` are made for ajax type requests. I think that if your `ajax_method` called is under controller  `someController` and if you have  `someController.js.erb` file, you should put it in `app/views/someController` and make sure you have somethig like that

```
def ajax_method
    ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm currently just calling my javascript file via my application.js file with the standard javascript helper tag like this - <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> is that not right?

Comment: The reason I ask is because css seems to work just fine without doing anything other than adding a .erb after the .css

Comment: sorry I don't really understand what you are doing, which and where js  files are called

Answer (score 0):

Ok i eventually fixed this by creating a new file and copy pasting the contents of the previous javascript file into it, pretty strange.